# Remove duplicate result from Permutation Function PHP if input contain same char

Tags: php

Actually this code working, but if input contain same char the result have a duplicate. This code i found here, but i cant find the solution to remove duplicate result when i try it self.

Here's the PHP code with an example

```
function getPermCount($letters, $count)
{
  $result = 1;

  for($i = strlen($letters) - $count + 1; $i <= strlen($letters); $i++) {
    $result *= $i;
 }
  return $result;
}


function getPerm($letters, $count, $index)
{
  $result = '';
  for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++)
  {
    $pos = $index % strlen($letters);
    $result .= $letters[$pos];
    $index = ($index-$pos)/strlen($letters);
    $letters = substr($letters, 0, $pos) . substr($letters, $pos+1);

  }

  return $result;
```

For the example

```
$letters = 'abcc';
$cek = 2;

for($i = 0; $i < getPermCount($letters, $cek); $i++) {

    $gege =  getPerm($letters, $cek, $i).","; 
    echo $gege;
    }
```

result

> ab,ba,ca,ca,ac,bc,cb,cb,ac,bc,cc,cc,

I want the duplicate result removed, exactly like this

> ab,ba,ca,ac,bc,cb,cc,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass your result to an array and then remove the duplicated ones and pass back to string.

First you use `explode()` on your string to create an array using the `,` as separator:

```
$array = explode(",", $gege)
```

Then you can use `array_unique()` to remove duplicated values from the array:

```
$array_unique = array_unique($array);
```

When you have the array with unique values you just need to transform it back to string, you can use `implode()` and indicate `,` as a separator again for it:

```
$unique_string = implode("," $array_unique);
```

Fast example:

```
$gege = "ab,ba,ca,ca,ac,bc,cb,cb,ac,bc,cc,cc,";

echo implode(",",array_unique(explode(",", $gege)));
```

You can create a function to do it:

```
function stringUnique($string, $separator){

  return implode($separator,array_unique(explode($separator, $string)));

}
```

Then after your permutation you can just run the function like this:

```
$gege = "";
for($i = 0; $i < getPermCount($letters, $cek); $i++) {
    $gege .=  getPerm($letters, $cek, $i).","; 
}
echo stringUnique($gege, ",");
```

Comment: @script888 You can check there how it works: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/fd28a1e09aa7c03ad2f6fc0b6fa7da8c57e983df

Comment: Thank's before, but when you try full code it not working, 
Please check http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/371902fc3356d66b9e20c945b5d6923723840a74

Comment: You are applying Troyer's function to every permutation on its own. You need to apply it to the result. [Working here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/9521c5595785710731512943e433e1de04bbd7de)